# The connection was reset (PhpStorm and Docker) Mac

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, php-5.3

I'm having a issue where I cannot access the Docker container on localhost, I get the message below:

> The connection was reset
>
> - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

#### PhpStorm setting images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Deploy logs:

```
Deploying 'PHP_5.3.29 Image id: sha256:ad27a04cf9f0'...
Existing container found: 5111d7f5efd8781548ab67a9074c26b5fac8c92b8575a3b993a59944dec67727, removing...
Creating container...
Container Id: 45cba31709be534f62f48113772e187fb5afe35b10e58d4fc24ee84d865ee348
Container name: 'PHP_5.3.29'
Attaching to container 'PHP_5.3.29'...
Starting container 'PHP_5.3.29'
'PHP_5.3.29 Image id: sha256:ad27a04cf9f0' has been deployed successfully.
```

#### Log:

```
[15-Jan-2019 13:21:10] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[15-Jan-2019 13:21:10] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[15-Jan-2019 13:21:10] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[15-Jan-2019 13:21:10] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

#### docker container ls -a:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
45cba31709be        ad27a04cf9f0        "php-fpm"           9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 9000/tcp   PHP_5.3.29
```

#### curl 127.0.0.1:80

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Are you sure that php-fpm listens to 80 port?
Could the 80 port on host machine will be listened by other process?

Comment: @IvanOvcharenko - thats what is says in terminal image ( https://i.imgur.com/8kQrj4G.png)

Comment: I meant web-server configuration inside the container.

Comment: web-server configuration conatiner is set to port 80

Comment: I downloaded the image, ran it and here what I see from inside the container:
php-fpm   1     root    8u     IPv4             483611      0t0    TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
This means that web-server is actually listens to 9000 port

Comment: can you access the web server?

Comment: @IvanOvcharenko - thanks for helping me.